# What makes it so that scala.collection.mutable.Map.apply can be a LHS of an assign?

Tags: scala

I don't understand why this is allowed:

```
scala> val mutableMap = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int]()
mutableMap: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map()

scala> mutableMap("foo") = 1

scala> mutableMap("foo")
res1: Int = 1

scala> mutableMap("foo") += 10

scala> mutableMap("foo")
res3: Int = 11
```

I imagine the latter (`+=`) is an extension of the former (`=`) - but I don't understand what makes this a valid LHS in an assignment. Is it special-cased in the compiler, or is there some trait or class that grants this functionality?

Comment: Look at the `update` method ;)

Comment: I think it will be translated by the compiler to something like: `mutableMap.update("foo", mutableMap.apply("foo") + 10)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a special case handled by the compiler. It's syntactic sugar.

[The language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) covers all of this, though it can be rather difficult to find things in that document.

---

#### `x(i) = e` means `x.update(i, e)`

From section 6.15 ("Assigments"):

> An assignment `f(args) = e` with a function application to the left of the `=` operator is interpreted as `f.update(args, e)`, i.e. the invocation of an `update` function defined by `f`.
>
> Here are some assignment expressions and their equivalent expansions.
>
> ```
> x.f = e                x.f_=(e)
> x.f() = e              x.f.update(e)
> x.f(i) = e             x.f.update(i, e)
> x.f(i, j) = e          x.f.update(i, j e)
> ```

So `mutableMap("foo") = 1` expands to `mutableMap.update("foo", 1)`.

---

#### `l += r` means `l = l + r`

Section 6.12.4 describes how `+=` works. The expression `l += r` is reinterpreted as `l = l + r` (unless `l` has a `+=` method, in which case it's typical infix notation for `l.+=(r)`).

---

Applying both rules, we get this sequence of expansions:

- `mutableMap("foo") += 10`
- `mutableMap("foo") = mutableMap("foo") + 10`
- `mutableMap.update("foo", mutableMap("foo") + 10)`

Comment: Is there also some information on `+=` and it's translation with `update`?

Comment: Section 6.12.4 describes how `+=` works. If you have `l += r`, either `l` has a `+=` method, or the expression is reinterpreted as `l = l + r`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that `+=` was part of the question. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Should `x.f_=e` be `x.f_=(e)`?